# Loading a xlsx file into pig relation

Tags: csv, apache-pig

I am trying to load a xlsx file into pig relation. The file can contain data with "," as part of the data. So I cannot convert that as a CSV and load it. So I am attempting to load the xlsx file as such into a pig relation and take it up for further processing.

But I am not sure as to how to load a xlsx file into a pig relation. I tried a few  options like given below but no success. When I dump the data, it doesnt give any readable output.

Sample data in xlsx file

ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC

IN       003    Advocate

IN       004    Business

IN       005    Accountant, CA

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
Data = load '/user/cloudera/kbk/occcd.xlsx' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') as (country:chararray,ccode:chararray;cdesc;chararray);
```

and

```
a = load '' Using PigStorage('\t') As (country:chararray,ccode:chararray;cdesc;chararray);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In Excel you have the option of saving the file as tab-delimited "Text (Tab delimited)(*.txt)". Then load that tab-delimited file into Pig, using tab (default) as field separator. That way, comma in the data is preserved.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I shall check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax issue with your schema.Field:datatype declaration must be separated by ':' and Fields  ','.

```
(country:chararray,ccode:chararray;cdesc;chararray);
```

Change it to

```
(country:chararray,ccode:chararray,cdesc:chararray);
```

Comment: Hi, That was a typo. I have checked with the correct syntax that has been given here. But I am not getting any proper output.